# Why does not this expression work in MS-ACCESS SQL View

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

```
SELECT
    Pname,
    Dname,
    COUNT(WO.Essn),
    SUM(WO.Hours)
FROM
    PROJECT AS P,
    WORKS_ON AS WO,
    DEPARTMENT AS D
WHERE
    P.Dnum = D.Dnumber
    AND P.Pnumber = WO.Pno 
GROUP_BY Pno
HAVING
    COUNT(WO.Essn) > 1;
```

I am getting

> in query expression . (Error 3075)

error with this code. What should I change

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're `group by` statement is not correct:

```
SELECT
    Pname,
    Dname,
    COUNT(WO.Essn),
    SUM(WO.Hours)
FROM
    PROJECT AS P,
    WORKS_ON AS WO,
    DEPARTMENT AS D
WHERE
    P.Dnum = D.Dnumber
    AND P.Pnumber = WO.Pno
GROUP BY  
    Pname,
    Dname
HAVING
    COUNT(WO.Essn) > 1;
```

Comment: It still says something wrong with WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  In MS Access, this looks like:

```
SELECT P.Pname, D.Dname,
       COUNT(WO.Essn), SUM(WO.Hours)
FROM (PROJECT AS P INNER JOIN
      WORKS_ON AS WO
      ON P.Pnumber = WO.Pno 
     ) INNER JOIN
     DEPARTMENT AS D
     ON P.Dnum = D.Dnumber
GROUP_BY P.Pname, D.Dname
HAVING COUNT(WO.Essn) > 1;
```